# Enzyme unit testing onChange method using Material UI Components

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

How would i be able to unit-test onChange method on this component.

**Comment.js**

```
import React  from "react";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
const Comment = (props) => (
    <div>

        <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
             <TextField
                type="text"
                id="outlined-multiline-static"
                label="Write A Comment"
                multiline
                name="comment_body"
                value={props.commentBody}
                rows="10"
                fullWidth
                margin="normal"
                variant="outlined"
                onChange={props.commentChange}
            />
            {/* <Button type="submit" variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
                Post A Comment
            </Button> */}
             <button type="submit" variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
                Write a Comment
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
)

export default Comment;
```

This is my attempt to unit test the onChange component, getting a

> Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

around this line

`const component = shallow(<Comment commentChange={onChangeMock} commentBody={'test'} />)`
`component.find('input').simulate('change');`

Comment.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import Comment from './Comment';




describe('Should render <Comment/> component', () => {

    it('Should render form', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Comment/>)
        // wrapper.find('Form').at(0)
        expect(wrapper.find("form")).toHaveLength(1); // checks if there is a form. 

    })

    it('Should render button', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Comment/>)
        expect(wrapper.find('button')).toHaveLength(1);
    })

    it('should check for onChange method', () => {
        // const wrapper = shallow(<Comment onChange={}/>)
        const onChangeMock = jest.fn();
        // const event = {
        //     preventDefualt(){},
        //     target: {
        //         value: 'testing'
        //     }
        // }
        const component = shallow(<Comment commentChange={onChangeMock} commentBody={'test'} />)
        component.find('input').simulate('change');
        expect(onChangeMock).toBeCalledWith('test')
    })



})
```

The Comment component is being passed in another component like this:

**ImageContainer.js**

```
 state = {
      isComment: false,
      comment_body: ""
    }
    handleCommentChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
           comment_body: e.target.value
        })             
    }

    commentSubmit = (event, id) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.comment_body); // doesn't get console.log
        // note that commentBody is being used for the req.body as well so its called by req.body.commentBody
        const commentBody = this.state.comment_body
        const data = {   
            commentBody,
            id
        }   
        this.props.postComment(data);
        this.setState({
            comment_body: ''
        })

    }

    <Comment onSubmit={(e) => this.commentSubmit(e, img.id)} 
                commentBody={this.state.comment_body } 
                commentChange={this.handleCommentChange}/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are having the error is because when you call `component.find('input')` it returns an array of matched components, so what you want to do is

1. `component.find('input').at(0).simulate('change')`

However, there is another way you can test this, which is my preferred method.

2. `component.find('input').at(0).props().onChange()`

Below is the correct way to do the test with both methods

```
import React from "react";
import Enzyme, { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import Comment from "./Comment";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("Should render <Comment/> component", () => {
  it("should check for onChange method (1)", () => {
    // const wrapper = shallow(<Comment onChange={}/>)
    const onChangeMock = jest.fn();

    const component = shallow(
      <Comment commentChange={onChangeMock} commentBody={"test"} />
    );
    component
      .find(TextField)
      .at(0)
      .simulate("change", "test");
    expect(onChangeMock).toBeCalledWith("test");
  });

  it("should check for onChange method (2)", () => {
    // const wrapper = shallow(<Comment onChange={}/>)
    const onChangeMock = jest.fn();

    const component = shallow(
      <Comment commentChange={onChangeMock} commentBody={"test"} />
    );
    component
      .find(TextField)
      .at(0)
      .props()
      .onChange();
    expect(onChangeMock).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

For this particular test it will be better if you just use `toBeCalled` rather than `toBeCalledWith`. There is no need to test the value it is called with.

Comment: ok will try this out, does the components look fine, any other mistakes you found in the code .

Comment: im getting `Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.` could it be an error with Material UI

Comment: because `<Input/>` is from material UI

Comment: @randal yeah same issue, you need to call .at I will update the answer, then you need to make sure `component` is the correct element you are calling find on

Comment: i just imported TextField and `component.find(TextField).props().onChange()`

Comment: @randal Give me a few minutes I will send you a working example

Comment: `Expected mock function to have been called with:
      "test"
    as argument 1, but it was called with
      undefined.`

Comment: @randal there you go

Comment: thanks this works fine, thanks for the explanation as well.